# iOS datePicker with individual month, day fields

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

I am trying to create an appointment application for iPad. When creating new appointments, I select date using `UIDatePicker` with `UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime` but found that I cant have individual scrollers for month and day.

Is implementing my own custom `UIPicker` the only way? or does anyone know if there are already available ones out there that I can implement?

Many thanks!

Comment: If you want date AND time in one picker then no. You can't have that with the standard date picker. But you can have separate day and month in the UIDatePickerModeDate one.

Comment: so my best bet is to create two separate pickers one using UIDatePickerModeDate and another using UIDatePickerModeTime? hmmm okay

Comment: That would be the easiest approach I think.